# Debugging an elusive edge case where browser reloads randomly

Tags: reactjs, django, web, apollo

I've spent weeks trying to figure out this bug. My app has a client where a specific page will reload after she's spent some time filling in new information in a form.

I can't figure out any reason for the page to reload. There are no error messages. Nothing is being captured in Sentry. So I can't reproduce locally.

How do I even start going about this... could I do some sort of context capture when listening to the page reloading event? As I'm not aware of any captured necessary information I'm not even sure what do send to sentry.

I'll try and save the unsaved data to local storage. But... any ideas on how to go about this is much appreciated.

Comment: is that component wrapped inside ErrorBoundry and by reload do you mean refresh?

Comment: it is wrapped inside an ErrorBoundary, and yes I do mean refresh. Although, I never refresh the page in the ErrorBoundary...! Also any error that goes to the boundary gets sent to Sentry. Which this isn't.

Comment: I just read this; https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html about how errored components are completely unmounted in react 16... but, as I have a top component boundary, it should still be caught by the boundary